# DRF: Should you manually handle exception?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm developing API for the first time using Django REST framework.

I wanted to know which of the bellow type is recommended programming practice.

In Code Type 1 if no record is found then I return None, which is checked in the main retrieve method. If None is received in retrieve method, I manually return a response with 404 status. If any other error (including exception) is encountered I manually return 500 response.

In Code Type 2 if no record is found then I raise Http404. The raised Http404 condition is handled by serializer and a proper 404 response is sent along with message.
I primary concern with Code Type 2 is will the code crash if any other exception is generated (as we don't have try-except block.

What is the recommended design pattern for API development?

Code Type 1:

```
def get_object(self, ca_number):#get single customer
    try:
        return CustomerDetailModel.objects.get(ca_number=ca_number)
    except CustomerDetailModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None    

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None): 
    try:
        data =self.get_object(ca_number = pk)
        if data == None: #Check if None, if true send 404 error
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = CustomerDetailSerializer(data)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except :
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Code Type 2 :

```
def get_object(self, ca_number):#get single customer
    try:
        return CustomerDetailModel.objects.get(ca_number=ca_number)
    except CustomerDetailModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None): 
    data = self.get_object(ca_number = pk)
    serializer = CustomerDetailSerializer(data)
    return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no need to return `HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` manually since Django will do that for you in case of any uncaught exceptions.

Secondly, if we only choose between your code examples, I'd go with the second one.

But Django and DRF are awesome, so for generic views (which is your case), they can do most of the work for you, thus no need to reinvent the wheel. Your code can be simplified to this:

```py
# views.py
class CustomerDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomerDetailSerializer
    queryset = CustomerDetailModel.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "ca_number"

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [path("customer_detail/<ca_number>/", CustomerDetailView.as_view(), name="detail")]
```

If you're using a `ModelViewSet` rather than a `RetrieveAPIView` the view class will look pretty much the same, but the `urls.py` should be changed to use the router.

Comment: In case of HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR DRF sends the entire error webpage to the client which I would like to avoid and rather send a customized error message or some standard error message. How can I achieve this with my second code sample.

Comment: Normally a `500` error means "something went terribly wrong", so it should never be returned. If something is expected to fail and you want to return an error message, then a `400` status is more appropriate. It can be returned either explicitly, or with `raise rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError(message)`.

But I don't see anything that can raise an exception in your first code sample - `get_object()` and `Serializer` handle most of their own exceptions. Anyway, if it does - it should be fixed/handled where it's raised, rather than in `retrieve`.

Comment: I'm using a database instance hosted on cloud (Database as a service). How will lost connection be reported? Do I need to create a custom error message or will DRF handle it.